# How can I identify the same character found in 2 Strings in Excel?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Suppose I have `ABC` in cell `A1` and `XaA` in cell `B1`.

Taking into account upper and lower case, I would like to recognize that `A` is present in both strings.

Below is the formula I tried using:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(FILTER(FLATTEN(FILTER(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(E1),
REPT("(.)", LEN(E1))),REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(E1), 
REPT("(.)", LEN(E1)))<>"")),
FLATTEN(FILTER(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(E1), 
REPT("(.)", LEN(E1))),REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(E1), 
REPT("(.)", LEN(E1)))<>""))<>"")&""&TRANSPOSE
(FILTER(FLATTEN(FILTER(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(E2), 
REPT("(.)", LEN(E2))),REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(E2), 
REPT("(.)", LEN(E2)))<>"")), FLATTEN(FILTER(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(E2), 
REPT("(.)", LEN(E2))),REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(E2), 
REPT("(.)", LEN(E2)))<>""))<>""))))
```

But it didnt work.

How can I do this using Excel or Google Sheets function?

Thank you.

Comment: Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel have different feature sets. Choose one or the other. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74671293/edit) the tags in the question.

Comment: Please show a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexmatch()` and `regexextract()`, like this:

`=regexmatch( B1, join( "|", unique( transpose( regexextract(A1, rept("(.)", len(A1))) ) ) ) )`

In the event you want to list the matching characters instead of just getting a `true`/`false` result, or if the value in `A1` may contain one or more special characters `.*+?^${}()|[]\`, use this longer formula:

```
=lambda( 
  a, b, 
  iferror( 
    filter( b, 
      regexmatch( b, 
        join( "|", 
          regexreplace( 
            unique(transpose(a)), 
            "[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]", "\\$0" 
          ) 
        ) 
      ) 
    ), 
    "(no matches)" 
  ) 
)( 
  regexextract(A1, rept("(.)", len(A1))), 
  regexextract(B1, rept("(.)", len(B1))) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

another approach... (handy if you have characters that needs to be escaped in regex)

if you untangle each:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A20, REPT("(.)", LEN(A20)))
```

then you can filter it:

```
=FILTER(C20:E20, COUNTIF(C21:E21, C20:E20))
```

[image]

---

in one go:

```
=LAMBDA(a, b, FILTER(a, COUNTIF(b, a)))(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A20, REPT("(.)", LEN(A20))), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(B20, REPT("(.)", LEN(B20))))
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE

to differentiate b/n lower & upper case try the spectrum shift:

```
=IFERROR(LAMBDA(a, b, FILTER(a, COUNTIF(
 IF((CODE(b)>96)*(CODE(b)<122), CHAR(CODE(b)+9301), b), 
 IF((CODE(a)>96)*(CODE(a)<122), CHAR(CODE(a)+9301), a))))(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A20, REPT("(.)", LEN(A20))), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(B20, REPT("(.)", LEN(B20)))), "no match")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a good way to avoid trouble with brackets and the like. Cannot think of an easy way to make this pattern distinguish between uppercase and lowercase though.

Comment: @doubleunary there are various ways but for example, we could shift lowercases into a different spectrum. see the updated answer

Comment: Yes... but `countif()` special characters `*?` cause trouble. Added escaping of regex special characters in the other answer.